# Inelastic Collision of two balls

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames, collision

Is it possible that two balls of the same weight collide (in 1 dimension) and then stay at the rest?
How is such a collision called?

What are **all** the possible situations (velocities of 2 balls of the same weight) how such two balls can move **after** 1 Dimensional collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a particular frame of reference, yes, two objects can collide and come to rest - this will be a perfectly inelastic collision. In a perfectly inelastic collision, two objects stick together and have identical final velocities, meaning they have zero relative velocity. If your frame of reference is moving  at that same final velocity, the objects would appear to have a final velocity of zero. In this reference frame, you'd see two objects moving toward one another, collide, and stop. Since a perfectly inelastic collision is the only one that results in zero relative velocity, it is the only type of collision where *both* objects come to rest (in a particular reference frame). In any other elastic collision, no matter what reference frame you pick, at least one of the objects will be moving after the collision.

Comment: This is a good explanation. But how do I picture/imagine that reference frame of **inelastic** collision at which both the objects will be at rest ?

Comment: @user2925716 In the common reference frame with respect to the ground, one object moves toward another, collides with it, and then both objects move away together with the same velocity. The finish-at-rest reference frame moves with whatever that final velocity is. For two objects of equal mass that collide in the ground reference frame where one is moving and one is not, the final velocity is half the velocity of the moving object. So, that's the speed at which the finish-at-rest frame moves with respect to the ground. In this frame, both objects move toward a center point at 1/2v and stop.